# Block and Contract difference?

Tags: contract-development, blockchain

I was looking to see the code of the blocks added to the blockchain at [Etherscan](https://etherscan.io/block/14674022) to determine wether the code is public. But given from the block information I see no way doing that.
I have read in several places that the code of contracts is public and visible. It was possible by finding a *project*. It leads me wonder what the difference between a block and a contract is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your question, but will try to clarify it.

smartContracts is code written on the Blockchain that can be executed/understood by EVM.

Block (in Blockchain), is just another link that contains data added to the Blockchain itself.

Block contains multiple transactions. Each transaction is either adress to adress, adress to **contract** or **contract**  to address.
By looking into transactions of a block and looking for contracts it's possible to view their source code by tapping the *Contract* tab in a [Contract's page](https://etherscan.io/address/0x5ad3ab21E91907bE576f05D26C4eeBF5b80db006)

It's better for practical reasons to look up the contracts by their address so it's easier to make sure they are up to date.

Comment: So I can view the source code of contracts - by looking at different *projects*. But I can't look into the contents of blocks?

Comment: To see the source code of the contract you just need to know address it was deployed to. But yeah, source code is generally easy to find. You can also see the content of individual blocks, but I am not sure what use it would be to you. Except to confirm time when something was deployed.

Comment: I am trying to understand how publicly exposed source code written in contracts are. Maybe blocks don’t have anything to do with it.

Comment: Anything written in Blockchain is public (If we talk of ETH Blockchain). Every block is just another page in the Blockchain ledger. That is the best analogy I can think of.

Comment: Following that analogy I can't seem look at the source code of that page - despite it somehow consists of smart contracts?

Comment: Usually (when looking for the source code of any contact) you will find it by looking at the address it had been deployed. Not into the block that deployed it. Reason for it is that if some other future block might contain some updates or changes the state of the contracts, you won't be able to see those modifications in the block which deployed it. Therefore (if you want to see up to date contracts) you search for it over its address.